# Getting sub element value using XPath where date is the element value

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Given this sample xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<currencies>
  <currency value="gbp">
   <Date>11/5/2020</Date>
   <Close>1.3102</Close>
 </currency>
 <currency value="gbp">
   <Date>11/4/2020</Date>
   <Close>1.2988</Close>
 </currency>
 <currency value="gbp">
   <Date>11/3/2020</Date>
   <Close>1.3049</Close>
 </currency>
</currencies>
```

I can get all the nodes by currency using

```
var xpath = $"//currencies//currency[@value='{currency}']";
var nodes = doc.XPathSelectElements(xpath);
```

But I cannot get the syntax right to get the node by date

```
 //priceDate is a DateTime passed in
 //this produces this xpath --- //currencies//currency[@value='gbp'] 
 [Date[text()] =09/15/2015]
 var xpath = $"//currencies//currency[@value='{currency}'][Date[text()] ={priceDate:MM/dd/yyyy}]";
 var node = doc.XPathSelectElement(xpath);
```

Any help appreciated.
I will ultimately want to retrieve the Close price in the xpath too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pay attention to the date formatting. With leading zeros or without...

Select **currency** element by the date:

```
/currencies/currency[Date='11/4/2020']
```

Select **Close** element by the date:

```
/currencies/currency[Date='11/4/2020']/Close
```

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky  I already tried this   var xpath = $"//currencies//currency[@value='{currency}'][Date ='{priceDate:MM/dd/yyyy}']"; but it produces a null result and Ive verified the xml is in the file

Comment: and the XPath string produced, looks exactly as noted in you answer(including the attribute)   //currencies//currency[@value='gbp'][Date ='09/15/2015']

Comment: I found the issue...The priceDate variable converts into 09/15/2015 for example but the file has 9/15/2015. what is the currency format to remove the leading 0 from month and day

Comment: @dinotom, I mentioned about zeros in my answer from the very beginning.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky yes, that's why I went back and checked it. This XPath is now working   $"//currencies//currency[@value='{currency}'][Date ='{priceDate:M/d/yyyy}']//Close"